# Passing parameter into a Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, asp.net, garbage-collection, task

Given the following code:

```
string injectedString = "Read string out of HttpContext";
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
 {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.Method(injectedString);
 }
```

Is this the best way to pass the string into the Task/Thread?

My concerns with this method are:

- Would the garbage collector know when the string became out of
  context and clean it up correctly?
- Is there a better way to inject dependencies into a Task breaking the link to the object in the main thread?

This is in a Asp.Net webservice, if it matters and is a fire and forget type thread, I'm not waiting for any kind of response.

My string is actually going to get read out of the `HttpContext`, which is one reason why I'm injecting it in this way (Thread does not have access to the calling threads `HtppContext`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your lambda will be hoisted out into a compiler generated class. The `injectedString` variable will become a field of that class.

So, it will be garbage collected when the generated class is out of scope (which is basically at the very end of your lambda), and the GC decides to perform a collection.

In response to your comment:

There is no duplication. The compiler turns this:

```
 string injectedString = "Read string out of HttpContext";
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
 {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.Method(injectedString);
 }
```

Into this:

```
CompilerGeneratedClass c1 = new CompilerGeneratedClass();
c1.injectedString = "Read string out of HttpContext";
// call delegate here.
```

Remember also: Strings are interned in the CLR. Even if the code was duplicated.. string literals will be interned in a pool. You would essentially only have a native WORD sized reference duplicated that pointed at the string (string literals only..)

Comment: That's what I needed to know. Thanks. So just to clarify, every reference injected will be duplicated in a new compiler generated class? So in memory terms I would have two unconnected strings?

Comment: It really depends on what you do with the strings. With what you've given here, the entire string declaration is optimized away and is instead replaced with the instantiation of the compiler generated class and the field on that class is assigned the value of the string variable. I'll update my answer to reflect what I mean.

Answer (score 11):

You should probably use the `Task.Factory.StartNew(Action<object> action, object state)` overload to pass state into your new task.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew((object myState) => {
    var i = (int)myState;

    //Do calculations...
    var x = i + 10; 
}, 10);
```

Comment: that code won't compile? Your casting s to a string then calling a method on it?

Comment: The DoSomething method on the string is just a sample.... Let me change for something that does compile...

Comment: Not sure it answers my question but it is interesting to see how the state works. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about `injectedString` may be "garbage collected" before `myClass.Method(injectedString);` runs ?

Answer is **no**. You don't need to worry about that, because `injectedString` is no more a local variable when it is closed in the `lambda`. It will become a field in new compiler generated class.

If you're concerned about will the garbage collector collect it at right time?
Answer is **yes**, It will do when the instance of that class goes out of scope and no refernces to it in managed code. That would happen certainly after `Task` *gets completed and gets out of scope*.

Comment: It was more the other way round, will the garbage collector know to clean up the string (or it could be an large object, etc.) once the thread has finished?