# C# .Net 4.5 Multithreading sharing variables

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am new to multithreading and have a question on sharing objects. I am doing this in C# .Net 4.5

I have an list that contains a object called Price. The class Price contains 12 properties one of type datetime and the others are of type double.

I then run 4 tasks which all reference this object List. None of the tasks will change the List object they are just reading from the object.

So the fact the tasks are all referencing the same object but only reading from it am I right to think that I will not need any locking?

Comment: You're right, no lock is required for reading.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing parameter into a Task.Factory.StartNew](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047046/passing-parameter-into-a-task-factory-startnew)

Comment: As in the question above, *Your lambda will be hoisted out into a compiler generated class.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the read does not modify anything for those types (and indeed most types), so it's safe.

Comment: think this already be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955819/is-listt-thread-safe-for-reading

Answer (score 3):

Until and unless you do not have `update` and `add` going on any other thread you do not need to add locking. If `update` or `edit` is going on any other `thread` then do consider to use locking.
[ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provides an easy and efficient way to provide advanced `Reader` and `Writer` locks.

Moreover as mentioned in **Thread Safety** section in [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx),

> It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List, but issues can occur if the collection is modified while it’s being read.